# Is it possible to completly remove Ubuntu's video player "totem"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mplayer, file-association, totem

To watch videos, I use Mplayer, which works great. But Ubuntu insists on playing every video file it encounters with "Totem", which I guess is a video player.

[image: Totem]

I use linux primarily on my laptop, and often on travels, where I have no internet access. All Totem does is launch, and say "should I look for a codec ?", and I have to click no before I can close it.

I know that I can choose "Open with mplayer" for various video formats, but every so often I'll have a file with a different extension, and there comes totem.

I do not seem to be able to remove it from my system, which really infuriates me. I left Windows to avoid programs that you cannot remove. :(

**EDIT**: If I can't remove it, I'd be happy with a solution to make all video files play with mplayer. I don't want to configure "play with mplayer" for every single file extension there is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's in the repositories under totem-gstreamer and totem-common, so you should be able to do it with:

```
sudo apt-get remove totem-gstreamer totem-common
```

Or by going into your favourite package manager and deselecting it there.

It looks like there's a dummy "totem" package that installs it all nicely, but for some reason in my installation of xubuntu it wasn't installed by default, so a `sudo apt-get remove totem` would just return "Package totem is not installed, so not removed"

**Edit:**
Updated the above to also remove totem-common, which it leaves behind.

Comment: isn't the totem package a dependency of ubuntu-desktop ?

Comment: Ah, good point. I'd assumed Ubuntu wouldn't just dump it on you. Fortunately, ubuntu-desktop is a meta-package, so it shouldn't actually remove anything from your computer, though they don't recommend that you remove it because they use it to "ensure proper upgrades". Try the apt-get command above with a -s, and it'll show you which it's going remove (without actually doing anything). It should only remove the ubuntu-desktop meta-package and not touch any of your existing applications.

Answer (score 2):

Does it work to go to "Preferences"/"Preferred Applications", choose the "Multimedia"-tab and change the default "Multimedia Player"?

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it shows "rhytmbox" as the "multimedia player". I think that's what is launched when I plug in a mp3 player.

Answer (score 1):

Look into just resetting the file association for any video type files.  This works exactly how you would expect it to and this way you can leave totem but choose your player. This article explains it step by step.

[Ubuntu File associations](http://linuxfud.wordpress.com/2006/09/03/ubuntu-linux-file-associations/)

Comment: Well that's just for one file type. I don't want to have to do it for every single video file extention out there. (+ dvd playback + whatever will come in the future).

Answer (score 1):

If —as implied but I am not that sure that it is indeed so— part of your problem is *really* that `totem` does not play your video files, then once when having an internet connection, try to play them and answer Yes to the questions about installing needed software. From then on, it will play your files.

UPDATE: suggested course of action, to be done once; open a console and copy-paste the following:

```
sudo aptitude install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg \
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad \
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-schroedinger
```

Please let me know if this does not cover all files you have.

Comment: I thought of that, of course, but won't I have to redo it when I encounter some weird new video file ?

Comment: You mean, apart from typical files .wmv, .avi (MPEG4 video), .flv and .mov? The video/audio formats are numbered, where do you find these formats? I'll update the answer.